# Session's storage and expiration in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new at Ruby/Rails, and I've got some questions about session mechanism in Rails and about sessions as a whole.

1. I've read that session mechanism in Rails 4 uses cookies as a
   default store. Is it true?
2. As I know, sessions are destroyed after
       closing a browser. Can I change time of expiration manually?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, sessions are stored in a cookie by default. If you look under `config/initializers/` you will find a `session_store.rb` file with the following contents.

```
Appname::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_appname_session'
```

As far as overriding this behaviour, you can create a custom cookie and set its expiration date to the time you want. Generally that's how user sessions are handled when creating authentication. For example:

```
  def sign_in(user)
    cookies[:session_token] =  { value: user.session_token, expires: 1.day.from_now }
    self.current_user = user
  end
```

Then you use that cookie to persist the user session.

Comment: +1 This works if OP wants different expiry times for different sessions. If you want to set a global expiry time for all session, you'd better set it in session_store.rb.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I didn't know that until I saw your answer, actually. +1 too!

Comment: Also - I'd like to store user_id for "sign in" option - this value will be encrypted using key from session_store.rb, wont it?

Comment: I would recommend against storing the `id`. Create a unique token and store that instead.

Comment: I saw this advice in some book, but I don't understand why I should do it if session's data are encrypted?

Comment: Because encryption can, and probably will, be broken if a person is determined enough. Using the user `id` might allow someone to hack any user's session. It's better to create a random token.

Answer (score 1):

you can set timeout using `expire_after` in initializer

```
My::Application.config.session_store :active_record_store, {
  key: "session_id",
  domain: "domain.com",
  expire_after: 12.hours,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes
2. Yes

Both of these things can be set in `config/initializers/session_store.rb`. E.g.:

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store,
                                        :key => '_my_app_session',
                                        :expire_after => 30.minutes
```